# Efficient way to create hash table in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Problem i am trying to solve:**

I am trying to create a hashtable for all characters in a string.

**Question:**

Is this the most efficient way to create hastable OR there are other in-built ways i can create the hashtable?

**Code:**

```
def createHasthTable (givenString):
    hashTable = {}
    for characters in givenString:
        hashTable.update({hash(characters): characters})
    return hashTable
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What you are doing here makes no sense. A hash table has keys maped to values. If you are just going to do `hash(value) : value` why not just use a list?

Comment: Why would you map the *hash* of a character to the character? That doesn't handle collisions at all, which suggests you don't really understand how Python dicts work. Do you just want a `set` of characters?

Comment: General principle: if you're trying to use hash values as dict keys, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the dictionary all in one go:

```
return {hash(char): char for char in characters}
```

or:

```
return dict(zip(map(hash, characters), characters))
```